# Test classes dependent on environment variables

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing

I have a class which is dependent on an environment variable. I would like to test it with a mock environment variable.

I think a good structure would be to inject the dependency in Spring Boot and then mock it in the test environment. How do I achieve this?

For example with the following code:

```
@Component
public class ProcessorClass implements Processor {

    public String readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
            String fileOut;
            String path = Environment.getVariable("READ_PATH");
            fileOut = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path + fileName)));
return fileOut
```

How would I inject `READ_PATH` such that I can then mock it within JUnit5.

`Environment` is a fake class that currently returns a value from `System.getenv("...")`

Thank you.

Comment: Consider implementing a fake class which is only used with `test` profile. You'll avoid trying to mock an environment variable, and it'll be easier to get the class to behave in the way you want.

Comment: Please could you provide an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a fake instead. It can be a better option when the alternative is something hard to mock. In your case you could of course just define test environment variables, but it can become confusing when the configuration is divided into different places. Not to mention that you might not want (or be able to) read *any* file in a test environment.

```
@Component
@Profile("test")
public class ProcessorFake implements Processor {

    // Implement without actually reading from a file
}

@Component
@Profile("qa", "prod", "dev")
public class ProcessorClass implements Processor {
    // Real class used with other profiles
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not told us what this `Environment` is.  If there is an `Environment.setVariable()` method, use it.  If not, keep reading.

`Environment.getVariable()` is a static, globally available function.  It was created without any consideration whatsoever to the question of testing, and it is not suitable for testing.  Therefore, it should not be part of any code which is intended to be tested.

Create a separate component, say `EnvironmentWrapper`, whose job is simply to invoke `Environment.getVariable()` and return the result;  leave that component untested, because it cannot be tested.  Then, in your `ProcessorClass` class, invoke `EnvironmentWrapper` to get the value of the variable.  In your test, just mock that class.

Comment: Apologies `Environment.getVariable("READ_PATH")` reads an environment variable. `System.getenv(....)`. This is the fake class i'd like to mock

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with SystemStubs - https://github.com/webcompere/system-stubs

There are a few ways to do it. If you know what the environment variable should be set to at coding time, then:

```java
@ExtendWith(SystemStubsExtension.class)
class SomeTest {
   @SystemStub
   private EnvironmentVariables env = new EnvironmentVariables("READ_PATH", "somepath");

   @Test
   void someTest() {

      // inside here, the variable is set, outside
      // it is't
   }
}
```

However, if you want Spring to observe the environment variable too, then you need to use a nested test class for the Spring test. https://github.com/webcompere/system-stubs/blob/main/system-stubs-jupiter/src/test/java/uk/org/webcompere/systemstubs/jupiter/examples/SpringAppWithDynamicPropertiesTest.java  has an example